# Comet with scala

Tags: gwt, scala, servlets, comet, rabbitmq

I am developing one application with GWT as client and my server side code written in Java servelt and I am fetching some data from another server.  that another server code is in Scala. so the question is how can i push data from another server to my main server and display that data to client using comet ( gwt-comet.jar)

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comet is something that your web server must support, via continuations or some other implementation (see [this](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/WhatIsComet) as an example). Usually web frameworks (like Lift) have some wrapper around this mechanism to facilitate using it.

I'm no expert on GWT, but for what you say it seems it has a Comet library. Using it should be as simple as to implement classes following this library specifications and using a server that supports Comet.